# android: generate traffic to saturate a specific wifi channel (programmatically)

Tags: android, embedded, wifi, android-wifi

I need to certify an embedded product, we are asked to write a software that **saturate a specific wifi channel with data**, in order to verify that we are compliant to the European emission regulation.
The embedded device goes into an anechoic chamber and should be able to emit data. I need to write the software to do this, java or NDK.

My idea is: Android goes in **AccessPoint mode**, choosing the channel. Then it starts to send **UDP messages to the broadcast address**, something like 192.168.1.255, expecting these messages are actually going on air. 
Is this assumption true?
I don't know if this happens, in case no endpoint is actually connected.
So, just to be clear:

```
socket.send(DatagramPacket(data.getBytes(), data.length(), broadcastAddress, port););
```

Is this function emitting packets even in case no client is connected to the wifi AP?

Any hints? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not to try with multicast packets?

Comment: @dash1e: Thank you, I'm going to try it. Easy to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an easier and safer way: change the beacon frequency.
In Android it can be changed (with root permissions) from 15 up to 65535 ms. That was enough to certify our product.